# RSA Archer - Calculated field based on Record Permissions field

Tags: archer

I would like to have a complete copy of a Record Permission field.

For example - I have a field "OWNER" which is Record Permission type.
 I want to create another field called "OWNER_COPY" which will always include the value which was selected in the OWNER field.
I thought of few ways to do so but none succeeded:

- Crete a new **Record Permission** field (OWNER_COPY) but it has no option to be calculated (it doesn't have the option:  "Set the value of this field using....")
- Create calculated **Text** field (OWNER_COPY)- but if I'm writing [OWNER] in the formula it will provide the ID of the value and not its name.(e.g. if the owner was "Oliver", I will get his id - "123"" in the "OWNER_COPY" field).
- Crete regular **Text** field (OWNER_COPY) and add a rule. but I couldn't find any kind of rule which can fit this case.

Any suggestions?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I too had a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596118/how-to-populate-the-name-of-the-user-who-selected-in-a-rp-user-group-field-in
I had to take help of data-feed to populate the user's name.

Comment: You can mention what did to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Archer can't copy value of RP to anther RP.
I used a custom object for this purpose. The limitation is that the field will be populated only when end user actually interact with a form. The good thing is that the field will be populated instantly.
As an alternative you can use a data feed as Tanveer described above, but in this case there will be a delay between the time when you save the record and population of the 2nd RP field.